# how to get contribution of features in feature set

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, weka

I have some features and I am using Weka to classify my instances

For example, I have

- Number of adj
- Number of adverb
- Number of punctuation

in my feature set.

I want to know the contribution of each feature in the feature set. What metrics or parameters are helpful to get the contribution of features?

Comment: We need a bit more information to help you answer your question. What is your classification task? Which learning algorithm are you using? Bonus: Which dataset are you using and what is the feature extraction mechanism? This information is not necessary to answer your question but it will probably help us understand your problem and approach better.

Comment: The measure of the *contribution* of a feature is highly dependent on the learning algorithm. For example, the way you would measure it for SVM is very different from how you would measure it for a naive Bayes classifier.

Comment: @imchelbarcher Thank u, I use DC and NB, also I am using the data set that I provide it by myself